# Disable https on pages that do not require it

Tags: http, https

I have created a website with a very basic contact form. I just finished securing the forms through https by making links to the form absolute paths with https://

Now, after I test the form, every page on the site I visit after is also sent over https, even to absolute links with http://

I would like the regular parts of the website to use http because they contain unencrypted elements, and I want to support caching.

How can I get the https to apply only to the form page, and revert to http if the user continues to use the website?

Comment: You haven't provided ANY details about your webserver, so we can't really help you. An answer with config details Microsoft IIS would be useless if turns out you're using nginx.

Comment: The webserver is Apache. Can you let me know what other details I would need to provide?

Comment: figure out where the redirect->https is coming from. disable it, then do a page-specific one with mod_rewrite or some httpd.conf `<filesmatch>` or whatever.

Comment: I now have it redirecting using RewriteCond 301 redirect for the single contact page instead of an absolute link, but the https is still carrying on to the rest of the website. Is that different than what you were suggesting?